# Problem with not printing entire Hexadecimal for input file ... missing partial header

Tags: python, file

I'm new to Python, so any assistance is greatly appreciated.
I selected a PNG image and noticed the hexadecimal doesn't include the full PNG header

code:
[link to photo beginning hexadecimal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHlG6.png)
[output beginning hexadecimal with missing header hex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITqPV.png)

```
import sys
from tkinter import filedialog as fd


# Converts file to a binary .bin file
def binary_convert(filex):
    f = open(filex, 'rb')

    for b in f:
        # creates and prints to Output.txt (need to change to temp)
        sys.stdout = open('OutputX.bin', 'w')
        bytes = 0
        line = []
        fileContents = f.read() 
        for b in fileContents:
            bytes = bytes + 1
            line.append(b)
            print("{0:0{1}x}".format(b, 2), end=" ")
            if bytes % 16 == 0:
                print("", end="")
                line = []
                print("")
# Main Program

# Open file via Windows Explorer
file1 = fd.askopenfilename()

# Converts the one files to binary
binary_convert(file1)
```

Comment: You don't need `for b in f`. You shouldn't be thinking about, or having any variable called `line` when reading a binary file - there are no lines. You should be using a `with` statement, i.e. a *"context manager"* for both reading and writing. Just read 16 bytes at a time and hexlify and print them.

Comment: Thank you for the advice!! I greatly appreciate it! By the way, I am a landscape photographer, too.

Comment: Also Thank you Robert for fixing my post. Much appreciated